# I need to have two 1-5 star rating fields, only editable by admins. Which plugin should I use?

Tags: plugins, plugin-recommendation, rating

I need the following: two different 1-5 star rating fields, for one of my custom content types. The ratigs will be stablished by the admin, so I dont need a real voting system. The fields are more like indicators than polls.

I tried gd-star ratings but its aimed at community voting and rating systems which is not at all what I want. I know this would be uite easy to code, but if there is a plugin for this I would like to know.

Thank you guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at

- [Easy Review Builder for WordPress](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/easy-review-builder-for-wordpress/)
- [Review Ratings](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/ratings-shorttags/)

they  both work as shortcode.